# HTML file attribute issue 

Tags: jquery, html, linux, ubuntu

```
<input type="file" id="file-id" />
<input type="text" name="file_path" id="file-path">
```

in **jquery:**

```
$("#file-path").val($("#file-id").val());
gives me : - 'C:\\fakepath\\test.py'
```

I am using `ubuntu` as my operating system. If I selected a file from `/home/mylappy/Document/test.py` It shows me the file path `'C:\\fakepath\\test.py'`

Answer (score 4):

> For historical reasons, the value IDL
>   attribute prefixes the filename with
>   the string "C:\fakepath\". Some legacy
>   user agents actually included the full
>   path (which was a security
>   vulnerability). As a result of this,
>   obtaining the filename from the value
>   IDL attribute in a
>   backwards-compatible way is
>   non-trivial. The following function
>   extracts the filename in a suitably
>   compatible manner:
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#file-upload-state

Comment: tl;dr You *can't* get the full file path. Not allowed.